# Including library with "/" character

Tags: c++, include

In some pieces of code I see something like this:

```
#include <SFML/Graphics.hpp>
#include <Qt/qwidget.h>
```

What is the difference with the "/" character compared to including a header like this:

```
#include <iostream>
```

I tried googling but I couldn't find any good results.

Comment: A header is not a library.  Including a header is *not* including a library.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Include directives are for including single header files. They essentially replace the directive by the file in question. A header file itself may be part of a library.

The piece before the `/` is a directory where the header file is placed, relative to a directory in the include search path used for compilation. Say my compiler knows to search in `/usr/include`, and all my `boost` headers are in `/usr/include/boost`. I can then include boost headers in my code using for example

```
#include <boost/some_header.hpp>
```

Comment: By any chance do you know where I can find the exact directory? I am using Qt Creator.

Comment: @that depends on your compiler. If you use g++, you can use the `--verbose` flag, and it will tell you all the directories in the include path. That, together with any directories following a `-I` in the compilation command, constitute the include search path.

Answer (score 0):

It just states that the header file is located in the directory `SFML` or `Qt`.